# How can I test that the stack is clear, in a mocha test?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, stack, mocha.js

In my code, there is an asynchronous function that doesn't return. When it gets called, it just runs some stuff in the background.

I want to test that a second function is getting called inside this function.

The problem is, I need to wait for `asyncFunction` to be complete before I can perform the check if `someOtherFunctionCall` was called.

Is there any way I can check the status of the stack to see that no function is currently running?

```
function asyncFunction(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        someOtherFunctionCall();
        console.log("Time Passed");
    }, 3000)
}


it('the test', () => {
    spyOn(someOtherFunctionCall);

    asyncFunction();

    // Wait for stack to be clear ??

    expect(asyncFunction).to.have.been.called;
});
```

Comment: _"In my code, there is an asynchronous function that doesn't return"_. That's a code smell. Clean code should be testable, without any need for workarounds. In TDD, you write your test first, then the code in a way that makes it pass the test

Comment: Wouldn't it be a code smell if it returned an unused value?

Comment: Not really, `setTimeout`, for instance, returns a value, even though most of the time, people do not use it. But in some cases, it's useful to be able to cancel it. In your case, maybe returning a Promise would be appropriate. You can "fire & forget" that Promise in your code, but be able to wait for it to fulfill in your tests

Comment: Cool those are good points!

Comment: Note the other way is using the done function, per the docs: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code.

Comment: Not in my case. I don't have a promise returned, so I don't have anywhere to put the `done`

Comment: You could also mock the async call (http?) inside your first function to return synchronously, so that you don't have to actually wait before the expect